# Creating python rows vs columns table with justification

Tags: python, input, iteration

Say I have to get user inputs for # of rows and columns, along with asking how they would
want their columns justified. Say for this example they want it right justified. How would I go about this?

```
numofrows = rawinput('# rows:')
numofcolumns = rawinput('# columns:')
for x in range(numberofcolumns):
    justify = rawinput('Do you want left, center, or right?')
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are asking how to request justification settings for the separate columns, which are `numofcolumns` in number.  The simplest changes to your program-so-far are to correct `rawinput` to `raw_input`, and add a column number to the last prompt, and save results in a list:

```
nrows = int(raw_input('# rows: '))
ncolumns = int(raw_input('# columns: '))
justify = []
for x in range(ncolumns):
    j = raw_input('Select left, center, or right justification in column '+str(x+1)+' by L,C,R: ')
    justify.append(j.upper())
print justify
```

For example, with `ncolumns = 4`, four questions like

```
Select left, center, or right justification in column 1 by L,C,R:
```

will appear, and if users responds with letters L, R, C, and L in turn, in upper or lowercase, the print statement will print `['L', 'R', 'C', 'L']`.

Of course such an interface is clumsy to use; on the one hand, if the user notices a mistake in column 4's specification after entering a dozen other specifications, it is necessary to start all over.  On the other hand, the program is difficult to use from a script.  The example code shown below does not address the latter problem, but does make it easy for the user to make column-justification settings in any order.  This code displays a message, `Select column justification settings, then click Go` and puts up a grid of radio buttons labeled L, C, R.  After the user is satisfied with justification settings and clicks Go, the program prints a list like [1, 1, 1, 0, 2], which indicates C,C,C,L,R selections as shown in following figure.
[image: grid of radio buttons]
This demo program does not input `nrows` or `ncolumns`, but sets `ncolumns=5`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Set up a simple horizontal menu with some editable radio buttons
import gtk
def bcallback(w, i, j):         # Radio button callback
    settings[i] = j
# create set of radio buttons
ncolumns = 5
W = gtk.Window()
W.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
W.set_title('Column-justification settings')
box = gtk.HBox()
W.add(box)

for i in range(ncolumns):
    col = gtk.VBox()
    b = gtk.RadioButton(None, 'L')
    rb = [b, gtk.RadioButton(b, 'C'), gtk.RadioButton(b, 'R')]
    for j,b in enumerate(rb):
        col.pack_start(b)
        b.connect('toggled', bcallback, i, j)
    box.pack_start(col)

b = gtk.Button(None, 'Go')
b.connect('button-press-event', gtk.main_quit)
box.pack_start(b)
W.show_all()       # Make menu available for showing
settings = [0 for i in range(ncolumns)]
print 'Select column justification settings, then click Go'
gtk.main()
print settings
```